# Find percentage over multiple subgroups

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a tibble of data for countries over multiple years, that I have grouped by the two columns: `year` and `country`. This is what it looks like:
[image]

Now, I want to calculate the proportion (or percentage) over this `summarised()` table, but only per year. In other words, the `sum` will only count the rows which have the same `year`? How do I do this?

This is the naive approach:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(start_year, sending_country_code) %>% 
  summarise(cnt = n()) %>% 
  mutate(perc = round(100 * cnt / sum(cnt), 2))
```

But I not sure whether `sum(cnt)` command is summing over the entire `cnt` column, or doing exactly what I want (subsetting by `year`).

---

You can get the dataset using

```
tuesdata <- tidytuesdayR::tt_load(2022, week = 10)
erasmus <- tuesdata$erasmus

erasmus = erasmus %>%  separate(academic_year, c("start_year", "year2"), "-", convert = TRUE) %>% 
  select(-year2)
```

Comment: It is easier, if you provide a data sample to work on.

Comment: within `summarise` include `.groups = 'drop_last'` and that should solve the issue

Comment: Applying your code on the shown data `erasmus`, you recieve `# A tibble: 290 x 4 / # Groups:   start_year [6]`. So your result is still grouped and calculated by `start_year`. Note: `summarise` drops the last grouping in this case, so after summarising, `sending_country_code` is not a grouping variable anymore.

Comment: Your code is correct. To check is out, just include `tot = sum(cnt)` within the summarize function, and then you can pipe `%>%slice_head()` to check whether the total is the same through the years or different for each year

Comment: @onyambu I just came to the same realisation myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that your code is already correct. Here are two steps to that I need to make sure:

1. Find the sum for each year

```
sums <- erasmus %>% 
     group_by(start_year, sending_country_code) %>% 
     summarise(cnt = n()) %>% 
     pivot_wider(names_from = start_year, values_from = cnt) %>% select(contains('20'))%>%
    map_dbl(sum, na.rm = TRUE)
#`summarise()` has grouped output by 'start_year'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.

 sums
# 2014  2015  2016  2017  2018  2019 
# 4966 26565 33200 33261 33645 32998
```

2. Back to the first data, and then calculate the percentage based on the sums

```
erasmus %>% 
     group_by(start_year, sending_country_code) %>% 
     summarise(cnt = n()) %>% 
     mutate(perc = round(100*cnt/sums[names(sums) %in% start_year], 2))
#`summarise()` has grouped output by 'start_year'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
# A tibble: 290 × 4
# Groups:   start_year [6]
#   start_year sending_country_code   cnt  perc
#        <int> <chr>                <int> <dbl>
# 1       2014 AL                       2  0.04
# 2       2014 AM                       3  0.06
# 3       2014 AT                      91  1.83
# 4       2014 BA                       2  0.04
# 5       2014 BE                      22  0.44
# 6       2014 BG                     133  2.68
# 7       2014 CY                      25  0.5 
# 8       2014 CZ                     125  2.52
# 9       2014 DE                     646 13.0 
#10       2014 DK                      27  0.54
# … with 280 more rows
```

**EDIT**
The two steps above can be made into a single-line pipe chains operation by using both `%>%` and `%T>%` :

```
erasmus %>% 
    group_by(start_year, sending_country_code) %>% 
    summarise(cnt = n()) %T>% 
    {\(x) sums <<- x %>%
          pivot_wider(names_from = start_year, values_from = cnt) %>% 
          select(contains('20'))%>% 
          map_dbl(sum, na.rm = TRUE)
    }() %>% 
    mutate(perc = round(100*cnt/sums[names(sums) %in% start_year], 2))
    

 # `summarise()` has grouped output by 'start_year'. You can override using the
# `.groups` argument.
# # A tibble: 290 × 4
# # Groups:   start_year [6]
# start_year sending_country_code   cnt  perc
# <int> <chr>                <int> <dbl>
#   1       2014 AL                       2  0.04
# 2       2014 AM                       3  0.06
# 3       2014 AT                      91  1.83
# 4       2014 BA                       2  0.04
# 5       2014 BE                      22  0.44
# 6       2014 BG                     133  2.68
# 7       2014 CY                      25  0.5 
# 8       2014 CZ                     125  2.52
# 9       2014 DE                     646 13.0 
# 10       2014 DK                      27  0.54
# # … with 280 more rows
```